# How to get the last row from each users?

Tags: mysql

im making a messaging system just like facebook messages section. where i want to display a list of conversations between the user and his friends. 
the fields of my chat table are

```
id,user1(varchar),user2(varchar),message,created_at(timestamp),updated_at(timestamp)
```

to retrieve a certain conversation i'm using a query

```
SELECT message FROM chat WHERE user1 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"') AND user2 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"')
```

but now i'm having trouble to retrieve latest(recently inserted) row of the message,the other user(the one whose receiving our message) and the time sent. which is to be shown by a list(just like facebook conversation list). 
it means i want a list of the most recent message (one) from each of the users on the chat table. or if im chatting with you i want to receive your name along with the message.

---

I came up with a query and I want you to see it its not the the final answer that i'm looking for but its pretty close to it.

```
SELECT sent_at,message,user1,user2 FROM (SELECT max(created_at) AS 
sent_at,message,user1,user2 FROM chats WHERE user1='Tiffany' OR 
user2='Tiffany' Group By user1, user2 Having max(created_at)) tb1
```

It returns the last conversation that the user 'Tiffany' has done, it means the latest messages send and received by tiffany. now i want to get the latest conversation either received or send by tiffany.

Comment: `ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo write this as an answer with a summary :-)

Comment: @Martin It's one of those questions where it seems *too* simple to be the actual answer, so I'd like OP's confirmation first :-) I'm assuming that OP forgot to explain something vital which is why they haven't thought of `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so (again, you haven't), provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @h2ooooooo  nope! this only returns the last message between two people, i want the others user's name along with the message.

Comment: @TRomesz So select the `user2` property? I don't understand the question?

Comment: @TRomesz you need to update your question, you need to define your criteria. Plese remember that we on StackOvefow know ***NOTHING*** about your situation outside of what you write in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what i wanted i had to use MAX() to get the correct conversation.

```
SELECT sent_at,
       message,
       user1,
       user2
FROM 
   (SELECT max(created_at) AS sent_at,
          message,
          user1,
          user2 
   FROM `chats` 
   WHERE user1='Tiffany' 
   OR user2='Tiffany' 
   Group By user1,
         user2
   Having max(created_at))tb1
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT message FROM chat WHERE user1 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"') AND user2 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"') order by message desc limit 1;

Comment: "order by message desc" - so if I start my message with "z" then it's counted as the latest? What?

Comment: do you have a date or ID column
order by that

Comment: He literally posted his schema in the OP: `id,user1(varchar),user2(varchar),message,created_at(timestamp),updated_at(timestamp)`

Comment: SELECT message FROM chat WHERE user1 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"') AND user2 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"') order by updated_at desc limit 1;

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
SELECT message FROM chat WHERE user1 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"') AND user2 IN ('"+user1+"','"+user2+"')ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I suspect the actual problem is slightly more complicated.

Comment: nope! this only returns the last message between the two people i want the others users name. it means if im chatting with you i want to receive your name along with the message.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then what you are looking for is a listing for the most recent message (one) from each of the contacts on the members contact list?

So, you need to grab one message from the database for each correspondant, and the one you grab needs to be the most recent.

These two criteria now mean that you/we can apply logic to the SQL to achieve this result.

So;

Usig this SQL table column format you have provided:

> id,user1(varchar),user2(varchar),message,updated_at(timestamp),updated_at(timestamp)

And using the assumption that the member whose messages you want to list is in `user1` column, we can construct:

```
SELECT message, FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(updated_at)) AS chat_time 
FROM chat WHERE user1 = :username ORDER BY updated_at GROUP BY user2
```

So foreach value of user2 the SQL lists the maximum timestamp value, which is the most recent message from that user.

---

What I wanted to do with this was that if the user is featured in *either* `user1` or `user2` to `GROUP BY` the opposing column, so if the user is in user1 then group by user2 and vice versa, however I can't easily get to do this right now and would probably involve `HAVING` which I don't have as much experience with as I'd like.

Possibly a `UNION` would do this but I would like to find a more neat solution here:

```
    SELECT message, FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(updated_at)) AS chat_time 
    FROM chat WHERE user1 = :username ORDER BY updated_at GROUP BY user2 
UNION
    SELECT message, FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(updated_at)) AS chat_time 
    FROM chat WHERE user2 = :username ORDER BY updated_at GROUP BY user1
```